# What exactly does framebuffer mean in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm a little fuzzy on the concepts of RenderPass, Image, and Framebuffer, especially FrameBuffer, but is it a piece of memory for storing pixel data or not, and if so, how is it different from Image?
Or does the rendering flow like this:
The rendered pixels are stored in Framebuffer first, and then in Image?

Comment: Do you know what [FrameBuffers do in OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)?

Comment: @Polygnome I just looked at it and still don't understand, the framebuffer is just a structure for combining several buffers?The GPU doesn't actually write pixels to it but to the buffer that attaches it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between framebuffer and image in Vulkan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557141/what-is-the-difference-between-framebuffer-and-image-in-vulkan)

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Vulkan are pretty much what the API suggests that they are. `VkFramebuffer` does not get attached to any `VkDeviceMemory` allocations (directly), so it clearly is not "a piece of memory for storing pixel data". The Vulkan specification lays out the role of a `VkFramebuffer` pretty simply:

> Framebuffers represent a collection of specific memory attachments that a render pass instance uses.

That's all they do: they hold all of the image attachments that a particular render pass instance will use.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is very clear, but if so, why did I get the pixel of the Image bound to the Framebuffer through texture2D() in shader not the pixel of the real-time rendering but the pixel of the previous frame, which means that the pixel is not written directly to the Image?There's a buffer in the middle, right?

Comment: @AndLightLight: I don't know what you mean by that. And since I can't see your code, I can't tell you why whatever you described happened.